# Relative performance impact of logging in Scala

Tags: scala, logging, playframework-2.0, akka

I've seen the following ways of logging. What's the runtime performance impact of each? Are there any other benefits of using one over the other.

```
val strValue = "xyz"
val intValue = 200

log.debug("This will log the string " + strValue + " and the int " + intValue) 

log.debug(s"This will log the string $strValue and the int $intValue" )  

log.debug("This will log the string %s and the int %d".format(strValue,intValue))

log.debug("This will log the string {} and the int {}", strValue, intValue)
```

Most of my current logging needs are inside Play and Akka projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are **no differences in the performances impacts**. The 2nd and 3rd approach should be absolutely identical. The 2nd one gets translated to the 3rd one by the Scala compiler. The  2nd one just provides a nicer syntax.

Having said this those log statements should have no performance impact at all. Those log statements get translated to the following. So it automatically follows best practices you may know from Java.

```
if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
  log.debug(...)
}
```

**So in the end:** Stick with what you like the most :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what translates the log statement to add the if wrapper? In most java logging frameworks the latter would be more performant as it would check whether debug was enabled before dealing with the string and variables, I always assumed scala would have a similar situation.

Comment: @AngeloGenovese Scala macros do, if you use a framework like https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging#scala-logging